# Is it easy to create a answer generator in php

Tags: php, generator

I want to create a question and answer generator based on countries for example, if I put the question, what is the capital of England? I want it to automatically generate the answer London. Is it easy to do this in PHP or any other language?

Comment: Do you mean an Artificial Intelligence that can win quizzes (not even remotely easy)? Or a game that asks quiz questions (fairly easy)? Either way, there isn't a concise answer to this question, other than writing the whole code for you (which is not what this site is for).

Comment: yet another quality question.

Comment: At least the question was "Is it easy?" and not "How do I do it?" XD

Comment: Fred -ii- grow some balls and stop being a sarcastic wanker. I am new to developing and just asked if anyone had an opinion on it, maybe a more intelligent person would of suggested a website or a book to read up on, or say it's not a one man job but more of a team effort..

Comment: If you read the question it say 'is it easy' that means I want an experienced opinion and possibly some suggestion and a way to go about it, is that hard to understand fred? But you would rather say a useless sarcastic comment

Comment: oh, I have balls alright and jam

Comment: freddyboy.freevar.com is this your website? It's just as creative as your answers....

Comment: This isn't the place, Daniel. Relax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you and your balls causing trouble again? haha. Anyways Daniel, you need to understand the scope of your question, what you want needs to account for various different ways people could ask the question. I mean, I could say *"What is the main city of England?"* on top of your way of asking. Accounting for spelling like Chris stated and many other options.

Comment: @Darren I couldn't find AC-DC's "Big balls" on audio, too bad. ;-)

Comment: si signore, and yeah, funny what you can put up in 10 mins.

Comment: Haha I think they are causing trouble! Thanks for your input Darren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say "easy" but it's do-able, and very time consuming. It's not something you could whip up in a matter of hours.

You have to account for mis-spelling, question format etc. and just pull answers from a database based on what you get. But it depends on how far you want it to go.

To make it intelligently generate the answers, that's another story, as IMSoP said, but you could take "What is the capital of England?" with a form, look for "capital" and "england" and then look in the database for what to return when that is asked, and output it that way. If it's just a few basic questions about countries then yeah, that's easy, and it will take a few hours to write, but a proper Q&A application is not something that is easy, or quick.

Comment: Cheers Chris, I appreciate your opinion